# Dask: Parallelizing across nested lists

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask

I have a problem with parallelizing across a nested list of lists.

A simplified version of my problem looks like this:

I have a list of lists:

```
[[a, b], [c, d, e], [f, g, h, i], [j], [k, l], ...]  # let's call this "L"
```

In Dask, I use a function to create them, because creating each sub-list takes a long time, and I have roughly a few hundred of them.

```py
def parse(filename):
    return list_of_lists

L = []
for fname in filenames:
    L.append(client.submit(parse, fname))
```

The key here, though, is that I would like to treat the sublists as a single extended list of elements (i.e. `[a, b, c,... l, ...]`) and parallelize another long-running function on each of them, but without gathering my elements and flattening the list. This is because doing the following also takes a long time:

```py
from itertools import chain
L = client.gather(L)  # the gather step takes time
L = list(chain.from_iterable(L))  # flattening is fast
L_future = client.scatter(L)  # the scatter step takes time too

def func2(element):
    """Also takes a long time."""
    ...
    return result

results = client.map(func2, L_future)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in a more optimized way?

Comment: As an aside, `list(el for el in chain.from_iterable(L))` can just be `list(chain.from_iterable(L))` but that shouldn't make a significant difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are a variety of ways of doing this well.

There is an example here: https://examples.dask.org/applications/evolving-workflows.html